# Difference between google appengine and actual big table

Tags: google-app-engine, bigtable

I know that app engine is implemented on big table, can anyone describe the difference between actual implementation of big table and google's implementation of big table .i.e (App engine)

Comment: It's the same. The keys are encoded differently for the app engine for per-app privacy, but I think that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bigtable provides a basic key/value store, described in the paper [here](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html). Values are stored in rows and columns. Row and column keys are arbitrary byte strings. For more details see the paper. The basic operations Bigtable provides are lookups on individual row and column keys, and ranges of rows.

On top of Bigtable, there's an abstraction layer called [Megastore](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/07/10/GoogleMegastore.aspx). Megastore uses the bigtable primitives to construct a more versatile database platform. It adds indexing - using separate bigtables as indexes - and queries using those indexes. It also adds [replication](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/09/migration-to-better-datastore.html) support. It's Megastore that provides most of what we think of as the App Engine datastore, such as composite indexes and the variety of queries the datastore provides.

Finally, App Engine implements a few things of its own on top of Megastore, such as the format of App Engine entity keys, giving each app its own datastore, and implementing certain operations like 'IN' and '!=' in an abstraction layer in each language's SDK.